# How to disable a group of elements in angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 3 text boxes and a checkbox on the top. now when i click on the checkbox all the 3 textboxes should disable.I tried like this but did not work

```
<input type="checkbox" (click)="method('total')" />
<div formGroupName="total" >
<input type="text" formControlName="first" />
<input type="text" formControlName="second" />
<input type ="text" formControlName="third" />
</div>
```

In component.ts file i have added a method which calls when the checkbbox is checked or unchecked.

```
method(elementName) {
    let element = this.form.get(elementName);
    element.enabled ? element.disable() : element.enable();
}
```

did not work. but when i send the formControlName of textBox it disables.. but i want to disable all at once ..to reduce the lines of code.

Could someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it this way :

```
<input type="checkbox" (click)="allow=!allow" />
<div formGroupName="total" >
    <input type="text" formControlName="first" [disabled]="!allow"/>
    <input type="text" formControlName="second" [disabled]="!allow"/>
    <input type ="text" formControlName="third" [disabled]="!allow"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a stackblitz with the solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bekdn3

In your component:

```
subForm = new FormGroup({
    first: new FormControl(),
    second: new FormControl(),
    third: new FormControl(),
  });
  form = new FormGroup({
    total: new FormControl(false),
    subForm: this.subForm
  })

  method() {
    this.form.get('total').value === false ? this.subForm.disable() : this.subForm.enable()
  }
```

In your template:

```
<div [formGroup]="form" >
  Total<input type="checkbox" formControlName="total" (click)="method()" /><br>
  <div [formGroup]="subForm" >
    First<input type="text" formControlName="first" /><br>
    Second<input type="text" formControlName="second" /><br>
    Third<input type ="text" formControlName="third" /><br>
  </div>
</div>
```